# how to know the name of the plugin when using with ionic-native?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I know the name of the plugin to add into the ionic2. However, when come to import it by using ionic-native, I don't know how to write it.

For example, my plugin is: **cordova-plugin-ms-adal**, and I install

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-ms-adal
```

But how to import this plugin? Is the following correct?

```
import {MSADAL} from 'ionic-native';
```

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is to dive straight into the source code of `Ionic Native`, you can find it [GitHub](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/tree/master/src/plugins). If we take the `Geolocation` plugin for example, you can see the following in the code:

```
export class Geolocation
```

This means that `Geolocation` is the name of the plugin you need to import.

However, in your case there is a simple explanation as to why it doesn't work. The `cordova-plugin-ms-adal` is simply not supported in `Ionic Native`. You could either create the implementation yourself and [create a pull request](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/pulls) to get it merged into the library or [open an issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/issues) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks. I did open a new issue on GitHub. I hope they will merge it very soon. I really need this plugin.

Comment: I can't wait until they merge the plugin into ionic-native. And I don't know either how to implement myself. Is there anyway to add and use this plugin without using ionic-native? Thanks